# A unique name from a string whose value can change

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem with creating a unique key that is created based on a string, but this string may change in the future and the key must remain the same.

Now more precisely. I'm scraping a list of products from the page with a unique name that looks like this

```
micro system TL-5 (2010 - 2014)
micro system TL-5 (2014 - )
```

So in the first case, there is no problem. I create a unique key in my database

```
micro-system-tl-5-2010-2014
```

However, in the second case there is a problem. Because now I create the key: "micro-system-tl-5-2014"

next year, when the manufacturer stops production, the same product will have the name

> micro system TL-5 (2014 - 2023)

And when scraping the manufacturer's website again, my system will create a new entry in the database because the same product will not be able to be linked to the same key that was created earlier.

Unfortunately, there is no ID on the manufacturer's website, so I cannot detect the same product based on it.
The only things are names that are unique, but as you can see, they can change over time.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? Is this even feasible?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use only the start year in your key, and leave out the end year?

Comment: This is why you don't use the names of things as IDs or primary keys.  Use a UUID or sequentially generated integer instead.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Did you even read what I wrote?

Comment: @k314159 Good point, I need to check if it will be enough. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're missing a few steps. 1) no, you can't do what you want. 2) You need to find a way to match new scraped entries to old scraped entries, and this has nothing to do with ID generation.  Then 3) Never use things that people measure or choose as IDs, because those things change when the thing you're identifying doesn't.

Comment: @MattTimmermans correct, I wish to use id but I can't

Comment: If you share the website and the table schema you're using, maybe there's another approach you haven't considered yet.